# Ошибка при установки Matplotlib Basemap Toolkit

Tags: python-3.5, pip

После выполнения команды *pip install basemap-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl*, появляется следующее сообщение с ошибкой: **Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Zakhar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tnc7scg1\pyproj\**

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потребовалось установить pyproj https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyproj